# File upload with nginx and node.js

Tags: node.js, image, file-upload, nginx

I am trying to configure nginx to manage files upload for node.js app.
I have followed this tutorial: https://coderwall.com/p/swgfvw/nginx-direct-file-upload-without-passing-them-through-backend

I have made it with the following configuration:

```
server {
    listen 80;

    server_name example.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }

    location /upload {
        auth_request               /upload/authenticate;
        limit_except POST          { deny all; }

        client_body_temp_path      /tmp/;
        client_body_in_file_only   on;
        client_body_buffer_size    128K;
        client_max_body_size       1000M;

        proxy_pass_request_headers on;
        proxy_set_header           X-FILE $request_body_file;
        proxy_set_body             off;
        proxy_redirect             off;
        proxy_pass                 http://localhost:3000/uploads;
    }

    location /upload/authenticate {
        internal;
        proxy_set_body off;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000/auth/isAuthenticated;
    }
}
```

And I did the test with Postman as follows:

[Upload post request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bakGE.png)

The post request :

POST /upload HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost
Cache-Control: no-cache

----WebKitFormBoundaryE19zNvXGzXaLvS5C
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="image"; filename="pic.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg

----WebKitFormBoundaryE19zNvXGzXaLvS5C

It works fine and nginx uploads the image in the /tmp directory. 
The problem is that the file is renamed as "0000000001" and when I rename it manually as "pic.jpg" and try to open it the viewer prompts "Error interpreting JPEG image file (Not a JPEG file: starts with 0x2d 0x2d)".

And when I run the file command(file pic.jpg) it returns: "pic.jpg: data".

Comment: have u tried saving it in some other folder rather than temp and then try renaming it?

Comment: Thank you for the reply, yes I did and I get the same problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could you check the Postman version?
In my environment, Postman(v3.2.8) has "binary" radio button on request method.

According the blog post, "clientbodyinfileonly" method is incompatible with multi-part data and supports binary data upload only.

So please retry request with binary mode(Postman or another method, e.g. XHR2).

Comment: Thanks a lot, like you have said, previously I was using multi-part, which is not supported by clientbodyinfileonly module. I have upgraded postman and  I've used the binary type, now after I rename the file I can open it.